# How do I calculate letter differences?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I would like to implement the alphabets into google spreadsheet and calculate the difference between one letter to the other for reading grading.

For ex.

John Doe reading grade level progressed from A in May to C in June(=SUM WOULD BE +2).

P.S. 
I'm a self learner when it programming. Beginner level.

Comment: StackOverflow may not provide very useful answers for questions this broad -- there are millions of way to skin that cat.  You will get more meaningful answers when questions are more of the ilk "Here's my code: _____, here's the error: ______".
Perhaps in your case you could opt for a no-tech solution where you manually specify numbers for each letter; otherwise you will need to find a function (possibly INDIRECT?) that can do this mapping.

Answer (score 1):

Each letter has its own numerical code indeed. The code can be calculated in Google sheets very easy, because there is [built-in function CODE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094122?hl=en&ref_topic=3105625). Consider the following sheet range:

[image: Letters codes difference]

Cells E2:E5 contain formulas: `=CODE(D2)` for E2 and similar copies below. The codes support alphabetical order and 1 as increment. That's all you need. For example, the cell F4 contains `=E4-65`, if you want "A" letter to be a reference point.

Be carefull, codes are case sensitive: 65 for "A", but 97 for "a".